# How to solve "Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()"?

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

I have this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

---

My code is :

```
<?php
$localhost="localhost";
$root="root";
$password="";
$database="company";
$connectDB=mysqli_connect($localhost,$root,$password,$database);
```

---

i've checked these solutions down below in this website and other websites :

- php(ini) in XAMPP and removing (;) before extension=mysqli and also the PDO extension.
- i've uninstalled XAMMP and reinstalled it.
- i've check this code on the other system and it was OK but unfortunately , not worked in my computer.

I don't know everybody has solved this problem by removing `;` before the extensions but this is not working in my system!

this is a super simple code but with a big bug (LOL)

Comment: It's not `new mysqli()` which have to be used, such as mentionned here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php ?

Comment: Yes. you need to install and activate the mysqli extension. And yes, this normally works by removing the `;` in the ini before the extension loading directive.

Comment: @Elikill58: No, it's Procedural style as mentioned here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php - the **mysqli** class would not be there, like the function.

Answer (score 1):

After removing ; before extension=mysqli you should restart your Web server
Also check in php.ini extension_dir= your extensions dir
if this doesn't work
Create a new php file and type in it

echo phpinfo();

And check if loaded configuration file = your php.ini dir if not

Go to apache config file httpd-xampp.conf and type in the end of the file

PHPIniDir "C:/path_to_xampp/php/php.ini"

After that restart apache and should work fine